# XML parsing Query

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax

Like in XML DOM, childNodes Property is there what is the equivalent in SAX?

I want to know the number of elements for the traversal, like in DOM,
 we can do,

```
for (i=0; i<node.getChildNodes().length();i++)
{
   //Traversal code
}
```

Similarly, what can i use in SAX?

attributes.getlength(); -> This does not solve.

Answer (score 0):

The length of an array isn't a function, it's a property, and properties usually don't have brackets `()`.
`var subnodes = node.getChildNodes().length // .length return the number of elements inside a array`.

Comment: I understand your point which is very correct. My question is basically to know the substitute of getChildNodes() like in DOM , in SAX.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent as SAX is a completely different approach to parsing XML.

In DOM, the entire XML structure is loaded into an in-memory hierarchical data structure, which has traversal methods as you describe.

In SAX, the only data structures held in memory are those you build within an implementation of the `ContentHandler` interface.  You can, as you parse the children of a specific node, hold onto data in a form that can later be traversed similarly, but there's nothing supplied by SAX.